# How to implement kafka connection pool same as jdbc connection pool

Tags: java, apache-kafka, connection-pooling

> I am having a one Kafka producer class that produces data with
> initializing connection every time, which is time consuming process,
> so to make it more faster I want to implement Kafka connection
> pooling. I searched a lot for solution but did not find the right
> one.Please redirect me to right solution.Thanks. My Kafka Producer
> class is:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class KafkaProducer1 implements ProducerService {
            private static Producer<Integer, String> producer;
            private static final String topic= "mytopic1";
            private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(KafkaProducer1.class);
    
@Override   
public void initialize() {
        try {
            Properties producerProps = new Properties();
            producerProps.put("metadata.broker.list", "192.168.21.182:9092");
            producerProps.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
            producerProps.put("request.required.acks", "1");
            ProducerConfig producerConfig = new ProducerConfig(producerProps);
            producer = new Producer<Integer, String>(producerConfig);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception while sending data to server "+e,e);
            
        }
        logger.info("Test Message");
    }

    @Override
public void publishMessage(String jsonPacket) {
            KeyedMessage<Integer, String> keyedMsg = new KeyedMessage<Integer, String >(topic, jsonPacket);
            producer.send(keyedMsg);
         // This publishes message on given topic
    }

    @Override
public void callMessage(String jsonPacket){
            initialize();
            // Publish message
            publishMessage(jsonPacket);
            //Close the producer
            producer.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Inside initialize method you can check if producer already exists return if already initialized. Close producer when done with all processing/application shutdown. Best way I would suggest is, use dependency container and inject singleton producer using dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you need pool of producer objects which can be always available when a new publish request occurs and wait for other request when the task completed,  your requirement may matches 'object pool'(A Object Factory with executor frame work(pool) in java) which is implemented by Apache commons as you need to get KafkaProducer object from the pool.  Object pool concept which is implemented and available in apache commons jar.
https://dzone.com/articles/creating-object-pool-java

Answer (score 0):

You can put all messages in array, iteratively publish it to topic and then close producer when done.This way only one time initialization and one time close or destroy gets called.You can do something like this

```
String[] jsonPacket///  your message array
 for (long i = 0; i < jsonPacket.length; i++) {
            producer.send(new KeyedMessage<Integer, String>(topic, jsonPacket[i]));
        }
        producer.close();
```

Comment: actually the scenario is that I am having a form,when I create new or update existing one with time span and not continuously , data gets stored in jsonPacket (single variable), so is your suggestion efficient for my scenario?

Comment: Ahh..in that case, you can check kaushal answer.Also you can put something like every few seconds application updates and write to kafka topic. You need to experiment this depending upon your application design